# Using spring-authorization-server, how do you retrieve the context/request from an in-progress authentication outside of the auth server framework?

Tags: spring-security

The use case I am trying to solve for is to be able to display some details about the registered client associated with an OAuth request when a user must log in via a form. For example, it would be great to be able to display a friendly name for a client. I can handle mapping this kind of data once I have a client ID, but I am unsure about how to retrieve the client ID (or other identifying information) about the originating request elsewhere in the Spring Boot application.

I looked through the codebase for anything similar to a holder (such as the Spring Security `SecurityContextHolder`) or anything that stored data in session, but I could not find any references. This data must be persisted somehow between the original request through the login process. How do I retrieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is handled outside of the framework via a `SavedRequest` in the session. If you're faced with a similar problem, this is how I'm fetching the OAuth2 client on the login page from a controller.

```java
    /**
     * Retrieves a friendly OAuth2 client name for the given login request.
     * <p>
     * In order for this to work, a couple of conditions must be met:
     *
     * <ol>
     *     <li>The original request must have been a valid OAuth2 request.</li>
     *     <li>The client must be configured with a friendly name.</li>
     * </ol>
     * <p>
     * If a client name can not be found, {@code null} is returned.
     *
     * @param session HTTP session of the request.
     * @return The friendly client name, or {@code null}.
     */
    private String getClientName(HttpSession session) {
        if (session != null) {
            DefaultSavedRequest savedRequest = (DefaultSavedRequest) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST");

            if (savedRequest != null && savedRequest.getParameterMap().containsKey("client_id")) {
                String[] values = savedRequest.getParameterMap().get("client_id");

                if (values.length > 0) {
                    String clientId = values[0];

                    RegisteredClient registeredClient = registeredClientRepository.findByClientId(clientId);

                    if (registeredClient != null && StringUtils.hasLength(registeredClient.getClientName())) {
                        return registeredClient.getClientName();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Nice! If you're trying to display the `clientName` associated with the login request prior to login success (e.g. on the login form itself), this looks like a viable solution. I will say that any techniques useful in Spring Security in general work here. So you can also, for example, register an `AuthenticationEntryPoint` that forwards to a custom controller with the `client_id` from the unauthenticated request in a query parameter, e.g. `/login?client_id=my-client`. That would probably be cleaner than relying on the session. But again, this looks like it would work in a pinch.